# Google Calendar API + Android

Tags: android, image, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm sort of new to this Android deal and I was browsing through the Google Calendar API in order to find a way to display a featured image for an event within an Android event calendar application.

I found out that if you turn on a feature in your google calendar, you can now upload an image as an attachment for any event you need to do so. However, the Google API doesn't really mention how to make use of that attachment. All I see are basic resources like: get, update, delete, create, etc...

Has anyone ever attempted to do this and if so, could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think you can attach event from calendar UI https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/154174?hl=en. As this is experimental feature I don't think this can be done through API.

Comment: :(  I guess we'll just have to wait for this feature to be added to the API...